# how to remove first two element if element repeat multiple time

Tags: php

this is my string:

```
$text = 'this@@@ is@@@@ my@@@@@ string@@@@@@@';
```

I have two question

1. how to remove first two elemt from repeated element.
2. how to add "#" tag in same element.

Finally, I want to get result like this:

first: `this@ is@@ my@@@ string@@@@@`
and finally : `this#@# is#@#@# my#@#@#@# string#@#@#@#@#@#`

Comment: mm, using replace, but take care beacuas ther is a pattern for replace, other for start str and last for end str

Comment: You say "remove first two @" so `this@@@` becomes `this__@` then you say "and replace them with #". So that should mean the string becomes `this##@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo str_replace('@', '#@#', implode(' ', explode('@@ ', $text)));`

Breakdown:

1. `explode` will split the string by `@@`, and returns an array
2. `implode` will glue the words in above returned array using  (space)
3. `str_replace` will replace `@` with `#@#`

Comment: Thanks @Sunmini Navaratnam